# windows batch script to read a number from 2 txt files and put sum in new file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a 2 text files and each of those files has only one integer, i need a %change of 2 intergers in a new file

Ex:

### File1

100

### File2

110

### expected result in File3

Initial 100
New 110
%Change 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off 
set "file1=file1.txt"
set "file2=file2.txt"
set "file3=file3.txt"

set /p Initial=<"%file1%"
set /p New=<"%file2%"

set /a Change=New-Initial
set /a changep=100*change/initial
(
 echo Initial %Initial%
 echo New %New%
 rem %changep% %Change%
 echo %%Change %Change%
)>>"%file3%"
```

Comment: I believe a percent change should be on output, not just a difference. But this is only simple arithmetic.